# Future Warning: Arrays to stack

Tags: python, numpy, vstack

when I try to use the following functions:

```
x_bounds = np.array([[   1., 100.], 
                     [ 0.01,   1.], 
                     [   0.,   1.]]) 

def generate_x_mesh ():
    X = np.meshgrid( np.linspace(*x_bounds[0], num=20),   # x_1
                     np.linspace(*x_bounds[1], num=20),   # x_2
                     [0, 1])                              # x_3
    return np.vstack(map(np.ravel, X)).T

def training_data (model):
    Xsim = generate_x_mesh()
    Xsim = np.vstack( (Xsim, Xsim))
```

I receive the following error:

> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:5: FutureWarning:arrays to stack must be passed as a "sequence" type such as list or tuple. Support for non-sequence iterables such as generators is deprecated as of NumPy 1.16 and will raise an error in the future.

Comment: `map(np.ravel, X)` this gives a generator object, change that to `list(map(np.ravel, X))` or `[np.ravel(i) for i in X]` or `[*map(np.ravel, X)]`.

Comment: @Ch3steR your comment would make a good answer.

Comment: @FlippingBinary I'll add it as an answer when I have some free time. If you have some time to spare please feel free to add it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

@Ch3steR solved the problem in a comment and this answer just provides some context to the already excellent answer.

### The Problem

`map(np.ravel, X)` gives a generator object rather than a sequence object like a list or tuple. The difference is not trivial, and some functions which used to accept generators may remove that functionality in the future. That is what happened here.

### The Solution(s)

We can unpack everything the generator object will produce, then put that into a list. There are several ways of doing this.

#### Iterable Unpacking

This is the most concise way to do it since [PEP 448](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#whatsnew-pep-448). It takes an iterable object such as a generator and unpacks it into a sequence. You're using the list as an argument of `np.vstack` so this does need the square brackets, but you could omit them in some cases.

```
[*map(np.ravel, X)]
```

Pretty simple, but there are other ways which may make the code clearer to other (or newer) programmers, such as...

#### List Comprehension

[List comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) has been around for a while and is a clever notation which iterates something with a for loop and puts the result in a list.

```
[np.ravel(i) for i in X]
```

This iterates the generator until it has no more objects by using notation which might seem a bit clearer than the iterable unpacking notation above. The `for ... in` notation should be familiar to most, if not all, programmers and the square brackets clue you off that this will be in a list.

There is another way which might be clearer still...

#### List Constructor

This method might be the way that shows the clearest intentions. You have a generator that you want to convert to a list, and you can construct a list from it.

```
list(map(np.ravel, X))
```

This works because you are passing an iterable object as the only argument of the [list constructor](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#list). The constructor will unpack that generator and return a list.

Comment: Great answer!! Thank you.